# IOS11.0.3 UIActivityViewController Copy link activity copies URL twice

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

IOS 11.0.3 `UIActivityViewController` Copy link activity copies URL twice.

```
func share(title: String, URL:URL, fromView:UIView) {
    let activityItems = [title, URL] as [Any]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = fromView
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = fromView.frame
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Copy and paste URL gets pasted twice.

For title `Hello` and URL `https://www.google.com`

On paste it looks like this.

```
Hello
https://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
```

Any idea??

Comment: Why don't you use `URL.absoluteString` instead of `URL` to share?

Comment: I've noticed this with links, iOS 11 renders the pasted link, if it doesn't find meta data in the link, then it shows it like that,  it's pretty annoying.

Comment: @trungduc URL is working fine in older IOS versions.

Comment: @Bilal yes, i mean that to solve your problem, did you try it use `URL.absoluteString` ?

Comment: @Baig links have all the mata tags like title, description, image etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that it's an iOS bug or a new feature ;)

You can check it by going to App Store -> Select an app -> Click `...` button -> Copy link -> Paste it. The link of app will be duplicated like in your question.

A solution for this issue right now is using `URL.absoluteString` instead of `URL`.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Although It fix the double paste bug but it leads to another issue. Any extension activity which only allow `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount` will not appear in the list if I use `String` instead of `URL`.

Comment: @Bilal i got it. Seem like you should continue to use `URL`. I think Apple will fix it soon. Or maybe it can be a new feature rather than a bug ;).